# Show posts of an advanced search form

Tags: wp-query, meta-value

I have created a search form with multiple fields, and I want to display the posts that match all the fields inserted in the search form.

For example, if I choose T-shirt && Red && L, I have back all posts with T-shirt as meta_value t-shirt, and all posts with Red as meta_value, and all posts with L as meta_value.

Here is the code:

```
<?php if ( ($_GET['product_color'] == 'empty') && ($_GET['product_size'] == 'empty') && ($_GET['product_type'] == 'empty') ) { ?>
   <h1 class="pagetitle">No Results!</h1> 
<?php } else {
$paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
// WP_Query arguments
$args = array (
    'post_type'                 => 'custom_products',
    'post_status'               => 'published',
    'pagination'                => true,
    'posts_per_page'        => 20,
    'order'                         => 'DESC',
    'orderby'                   => 'parent',
    'paged'                         => $paged,
    'suppress_filters'      => false,
    'meta_query'                => array(
        'relation'                  => 'OR',
        array(
            'key'       => 'product_color', 
            'value'     => $product_color,
            'compare'   => 'LIKE'
        ),
         array(
             'key'       => 'product_size',
             'value'     => $product_size,
             'compare'  => 'LIKE'
        ),
        array(
            'key'       => 'product_type',
            'value'     => $product_type,
            'compare'   => 'LIKE'
        ),                          
    ),
);

// The Query
$searched_posts = new WP_Query( $args );
```

How can I modify my query to achieve my goal?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1):

If I am reading your question right, you need `AND` not `OR` for the meta query `relation`

```
'relation'                  => 'AND',
```

I don't see where you've set the `$product_*` values either. You should be using `$_GET['product_color']` (etc), but you need to [sanitize that user supplied data](https://codex.wordpress.org/Validating_Sanitizing_and_Escaping_User_Data). I would use a "whitelist" technique if it were me:

```
$whitelist = array(
  'red' => 'red',
  'blue' => 'blue'
);

if (isset($_GET['product_color']) && isset($whitelist[$_GET['product_color']])) {
  $product_color = $whitelist[$_GET['product_color']];
}
echo $product_color;
```

If this is a secondary query you should be good, if this is the main query on the page you should be using `pre_get_posts`.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I replace OR with AND, but I think that my problem is this:  SELECT..........AND ( ( wp_postmeta.meta_key = 'custom_products' AND  CAST(wp_postmeta.meta_value AS CHAR) LIKE '%t-shirt%' ) AND ( mt1.meta_key = 'product_color' AND CAST(mt1.meta_value AS CHAR) LIKE '%empty%' ) AND ( mt2.meta_key = 'product_type' AND CAST(mt2.meta_value AS CHAR) AND wp_posts.post_type = 'custom_products' GROUP BY wp_posts.ID ORDER BY wp_posts.post_parent DESC LIMIT 0, 20.....the fields not filled have empty inside!